# interaction between adjacent components in angular

Tags: angular, components

Hi all can we please describe how to interaction between adjacent components in angular? not parent/child.
For example: i have two components (not parent/child, just neighbors). In first component i have bool variable which changes in function, and the second component must to know which value of variable in first component, and depending on the value of the variable, function in second component performs a different code block. how can i implement this?
thanks for helping.
 
1 component

```
 let bool = false;
     function() {
        //something to do
        bool = true;
     }
```

2 component

```
function() {
    if (bool === true) {
    //something to do
    }
    else {
        something new to do
    }
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template variable to reference sibling components (directives, elements)

```
<my-comp1 #first></my-comp>
<my-comp1 (foo)="first.something = $event"></my-comp>
```

You can use a the common parent as mediator, or use a shared service (provided on a common ancestor)